# How to solve message select2 is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

My code is like this :

```
$("select[name='country']").select2();
$("select[name='city']").select2();


var ccode = document.getElementsByName('ccode')[0].value;

$("select[name='country']").select2().on('change', function() {
  var otherValue = jQuery('option:selected', this).attr('data-othervalue');
  jQuery('#otherValue').val(otherValue);

  var country = $("select[name='country']");
  var city = $("select[name='city']");

  city.empty();
  city.attr('placeholder', 'Please Wait...');
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: BASEURL + "/../hotel/city/" + country.val(),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery.each(data.SearchCityResponse.Nation.City, function(key, value) {
        city.append(jQuery("<option " + (value.CityCode === ccode ? 'selected' : '') + "></option>").val(value.CityCode).text(value.CityName));
      });

      city.select2();
    }
  });
}).trigger('change');
```

> There is error message : TypeError: city.select2 is not a function

Even though I already loaded select2 library

`$("select[name='country']").select2()`, `$("select[name='city']").select2()`, and  `$("select[name='country']").select2().on('change', function()..` are no error, but `city.select2()` is error

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` library?

Comment: @SangSuantak wouldnt that give `$ is not a function`?

Comment: It does feel like, you have not loaded Select2. Have you wrapped this function around a document ready or something?

Comment: @DelightedD0D good point.

Comment: Just for grins, If you add `console.log(city);` just before that line, what do you get in the console?

Comment: @DelightedD0D, Yes I get it

Comment: @JeremyRajan, I wrapped this function around a variable

Comment: @samueltoh, but does that mean select2 is loaded. You might as well, put a breakpoint before the variable (function) that you mentioned and type in the console, and see if select2 is loaded. Otherwise, best to put it after select2 lib include

Comment: @JeremyRajan. I have load select2 library. `$("select[name='country']").select2()`, `$("select[name='city']").select2()`, and `$("select[name='country']").select2().on('change', function()`.. are no error, but `city.select2()` is error.  I'm still confused your statement. What do you mean by breakpoint?

Comment: Does your code look *exactly like the above*? If so, your code should work fine, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/fyhsz9ra/87/)

Comment: @DelightedD0D, Yes, my code like it. I'm still difficult to solve my case. I using laravel. View and js placed in different files. This seem occurs because select2 were in ajax

Comment: Try taking the `.trigger('change');` off the end of the end of the `$("select[name='country']").select2()` function. Does that have any effect? The way you have it now, the `.trigger('change');` is called onload which calls your ajax once before the user ever touches the country select box. It works fine in my fiddle, but if you have things in different places in production,  it could be that this causes a conflict

Comment: @samueltoh What error you are facing, you have to do console.log(); or alert(); step by step. it might be there is jquery conflict issue. it means your select2 library not working but included.

Comment: @Monty, I've solved my problem

Comment: @DelightedD0D,  I've solved my problem

Comment: do share, what was wrong?

Comment: @DelightedD0D, I load the two jquery. like this: 1. jquery library, 2. Select2 library, 3. jquery library. I remove be like this: 1. jquery library, 2. select2 library. and it worked